# Rerouting international traffic based on GeoIP

Tags: vpn, proxy, routing, geoip

My home connection is slow internationally but fast locally. My private remote server is fast both locally and internationally, but it does not pay off to use it locally due to proxy/VPN overhead. Is it a feasible idea to reroute just the international traffic from my home connection through the fast remote proxy somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one answer I've been able to find is to use PAC files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config